# Cannot import torch - Image not found

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to import `torch` but failed because of `Image not Found` error. Here is the error when I entered `import torch`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import torch

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py in 
    134     # See Note [Global dependencies]
    135     _load_global_deps()
--> 136     from torch._C import *
    137 
    138 __all__ += [name for name in dir(_C)

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libc++.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Thank you very much!

EDIT: This works for me:

```
>>> install_name_tool -add_rpath /usr/lib /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

Answer (score 2):

workaround:
cp /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib

It looks a bug in pytorch 1.4.0 & 1.5.0 on macOS when install pytorch with pip install.

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/36941

Comment: This issue was fixed in pytorch 1.6.0 on macOS.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by doing this way, suppose you are using the virtual environment.
Replace `YOUR_PATH_TO_PYTHON_ENV` with your python environment path.

```
install_name_tool -add_rpath /usr/lib YOUR_PATH_TO_PYTHON_ENV/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

If you are using your local python, maybe it will look like.

```
install_name_tool -add_rpath /usr/lib /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

Basically, you need to add rpath of your library to torch in your python environment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try installing the pytorch using the official command shown in the `https://pytorch.org`

Sample command for installing pytorch with cpu only in windows. Installation command varies for different environments.

```
pip install torch==1.5.0+cpu torchvision==0.6.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```